# Wave function and speed of light

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, wavefunction, wavefunction-collapse

When a photon is generated, it travels at the speed of *c* in the form of propagating electromagnetic wave until the photon interacts with something else to have its energy absorbed or converted. Is this propagating electromagnetic wave the same as the Schrodinger's wave function and the energy absorption or conversion the same as wave function collapse? Suppose one second has elapsed since the photon was generated, will the wave function only collapse at a distance that is *c* meters from the place where it was generated, or it can still collapse anywhere in the distance it has supposedly traveled?

Comment: Hi welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. "Is this propagating electromagnetic wave the same as the Schrodinger's wave function and the energy absorption or conversion the same as wave function collapse". No to both, you need to read this article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function

Comment: Hi and welcome :)
EM wave and wave functions are not the same at all. You need to talk in the second quantization language (QED more precisely) when you are interested in the EM properties of photons. Google for [EM field Quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_of_the_electromagnetic_field).

Comment: @MahdiKoorepaz, Thank you for pointing me to second quantization. Could you help me understand when a photon is emitted, after one second, can we still find the photon (wave function collapse) 1 meter away from the source, albeit with an extremely small probability?

Answer (score -1):

Sure you can find it. As a simpler example imagine a free particle in a very large box. The wave function of such particle is a plain wave  $\psi(x)=Ae^{ikx}$ where $A$ is a normalization factor and $k$ is its momentum. As soon you create such a particle, it can be found **anywhere** with the probability of $1/A^2$. Quantum mechanics does not care about *locality*.

Comment: Thank you Mahdi!